# Text from MS Word into QGIS print layout?

Tags: qgis

Can I add a text from MS Word into the QGIS print layout and keep the text format? (Words with bold style of text, words with different text sizes, and so on.)

My final goal is to export the print layout (with text from MS Word included) as a high-quality PDF file. I have tried to do the opposite, but the quality of the PDF file is low when I export to a PDF file from MS Word. (I exported the print layout as a .tif image and imported it to MS Word.)

(QGIS-version 3.16.10-Hannover)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to add a text box -

Save your Word document as .html. Then add an html frame to your layout. In the properties menu select URL as the HTML source, then point to the saved .html version of your Word document.

Comment: Nice trick.....